# XML Parser on MonoTouch?

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, xml-parsing

I want to parse XML formatted string. How to use XML parser on MonoTouch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Exactly the same way you would in standard C#.

Your options include:

[XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) - good if you want to translate a full document to a set of C# objects

[XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) - good if the document is custom beyond XmlSerializer can handle

[XPath](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/myXPath.aspx) - good for pulling out small pieces of data, if you don't care about the whole doc.

[Linq2XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) - another option using Linq.

Depending on what exactly you need.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) in MonoTouch.

So,

```
var element = XElement.Parse("<cat>dog</cat>");
Console.WriteLine(element.Value);
```

prints "dog".

Answer (score 0):

You can´t use System.Xml.Linq in full, there will be a JIT part that will blow up when testing in the device, see Xamarin Monotouch limitations:

[link](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/limitations)